# jQuery tooltip similar to stackoverflow

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I would like to use this style of tool tip (stackoverflow comments form on focus), how can i implement ? do we have any similar examples.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look into the [jQuery tooltip plugin](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/).

Comment: yeah i saw lot of tooltips but i need this onfocus only that to animated.

Comment: that's what I posted friend, just add that .tooltip() to your element, inside your onfocus

Comment: However a link to a plugin will need to exist, and the code impossible to show

Comment: oh, ok. though it's kind of permanent link, u r fair enough. Thanks

Comment: Hm..., any ways thanks friend :-)